# return a ajax output

Tags: javascript

I have a question.

How to change the ajax function so that it returns the value of output variable.

```
function ajax(url, data)
        {
            const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.open('post', url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            http.onload = function()
            {
                if(http.status === 200 || http.status == 0)
                {
                    var output = http.responseText;
                }
            }
            http.send(data);
            // return the value of output
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Its not clear what you want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `addEventListener` method. It depends on what event you are waiting for. If you are waiting for a click, you need to find an element at first `document.querySelector('#some-button').addEventListener('click', myFunction)`. If it is a custom event, you can add event listener to the document and then dispatch this event on document